# Eclipse editor line color

Tags: eclipse, colors, editor

Is there any way to make Eclipse **set the color of the line beginning with some expression** to a specified value?

In my code I got lots of working "Log" calls which I want to save until any production-like version occurs, but they make it hard to read the code. So I need theses calls (lines, or it would be better if it would be full construction until ";") to be displayed in some other color, like light gray.

Comment: are you talking abut the console view or the code editor? if you mean the console, what logger are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Task Tag, like "TODO", but use "log." or something like that.  And the task tag lines appear in a user-specified color.